# How to return the View with JSON result?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any way to return the View with JSON result? I've done like this but it returns me a json results only I want to bind json result with jQuery Datatable.

this is my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task <IActionResult> GetDepartments()
    {
        try
        {
            ...
            var result = await _get.GetRequest<string>(uri, accessToken);
            return Json(result);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           ..
        }
```

For my View I'm doing like this:

```
<table id="myDataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Department</td>
            <td>Manager</td>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: '/Home/GetDepartments',
                    "dataSrc": ""
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: "id" },
                    { data: "name" },
                    { data: "department" },
                    { data: "manager" }
                ]
            });
        });


</script>
```

That's what I got

```
[{"id":3,"name":"Sales","department":null,"manager":"Danial Booker"},{"id":4,"name":"PMO","department":null,"manager":"Rowan Walter"},{"id":5,"name":"Research And Development","department":null,"manager":"Shani Elliott"},{"id":6,"name":"Product Management","department":null,"manager":"Menna Goff"},{"id":7,"name":"HR","department":null,"manager":"Jayda Martinez"},{"id":8,"name":"Deve","department":"Product Management","manager":"Abigayle Briggs"},{"id":9,"name":"Test","department":"Product Management","manager":"Alys Huang"},{"id":19,"name":"QA","department":"Ava","manager":"Mela "}]
```

I want to show the view that have the Plugin jQuery datatable with json result, any help please?

Comment: Returning JSON only is the correct approach. What is the issue with the way you have this working right now?

Comment: The table and the View never show I want to bind JSON with the table

Comment: better to bind json once you fetch data

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: 'The table and the View never show' - this sounds like you have an error in your JS/C# which is preventing the datatable from being instantiated, or the AJAX request from completing. Check the console for errors and debug them,.

Comment: I did nothing wrong, what I meant is I want to bind json result into jquery datatable but what I got is only the json result without the table

Comment: I guess your view named `GetDepartments`, so it will get into your `GetDepartments` action and retun json. You need change your view name, for example, your view name is `Index.cshtml` in `Views/Home` folders, and you have an `Index` action in HomeController which only has code `return View()` in it. Then when the Index view renders , it will call the ajax call to `/Home/GetDepartments` action and return the json data to Index.cshtml.

Comment: You should have two Actions on your controller - one for the View and a *separate* one for the JSON Departments (it's hard to tell if you have this or not, but looks like it).    So the View renders the html, including the table and initialises datatables - then datatables calls your JSON action to load the data.  Your JSON action does *not* want to include any html / the view.  If it's working other than not loading data into the table, then the issue is the format of the JSON - it needs to be in a very specific format for datatables.

Comment: @Rena thank you Rena that's worked so fine.

Comment: @freedomn-m I tried it and its working thanks to you and to everyone

Comment: @BasmaAlmutiri I have made an example `DataTable` repository with ASP.NET MVC: https://github.com/rahsharm77/DataTableExample/tree/master/DataTablesExample . You can refer to this example and hopefully it helps you out.

Comment: Hello @Basma was the answer helpful? Do you still need any assistance on this?

Comment: Hello @MdFaridUddinKiron actually I tried (Rena) answer and it's worked with me, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to make an ajax call to fetch the data then you can bind it.
if you have data you can bind it in your data table something like the below example.

```
 var data = [{"id":3,"name":"Sales","department":null,"manager":"Danial Booker"},{"id":4,"name":"PMO","department":null,"manager":"Rowan Walter"},{"id":5,"name":"Research And Development","department":null,"manager":"Shani Elliott"},{"id":6,"name":"Product Management","department":null,"manager":"Menna Goff"},{"id":7,"name":"HR","department":null,"manager":"Jayda Martinez"},{"id":8,"name":"Deve","department":"Product Management","manager":"Abigayle Briggs"},{"id":9,"name":"Test","department":"Product Management","manager":"Alys Huang"},{"id":19,"name":"QA","department":"Ava","manager":"Mela "}];
 
 $('#example').DataTable({
       data : data,
       columns : [
           { "data" : "id" },
           { "data": "name" },
          { "data": "department" },
          { "data": "manager" }
      ]
})
```

here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/fwtmd87g/3/).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying now you should have two controllers; one for
fetching data, and another one for displaying the datatable into view.

**Controller For Fetching Data:**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetDepartments()
        {
            try
            {

                var result = await _get.GetRequest<string>(uri, accessToken);
                return Json(result);

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

**Note:** You don't need to add view for this action.

**Controller For Display Datatable:**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult BindJsonToView()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

**Note:** Add below view for this action as below.

**View To Display Datatable:**

```
<h2>BindDataTableFromJson</h2>
<table id="bindDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Manager</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/ControllerName/GetDepartments",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#bindDataTable').DataTable({
                        data: response,
                        columns: [
                            { data: 'id' },
                            { data: 'name' },
                            { data: 'department' },
                            { data: 'manager' }
                        ]
                    });

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Another easy way, you could try, you don't need to use two controllers, only need to use `ViewBag` instead of `Json(result)`  Just plug and play.

**Controller:**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult BindDataTable()
        {
            var result = await _get.GetRequest<string>(uri, accessToken);
            ViewBag.result = result;
            return View();
        }
```

**View:**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "BindDataTable";
}
    <table id="bindDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Manager</th>
    
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
        @section scripts {
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    
            <script>
    
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#bindDataTable').DataTable({
                data:  @Json.Serialize(@ViewBag.result),
                columns: [
                    { data: 'id' },
                    { data: 'name' },
                    { data: 'department' },
                    { data: 'manager' }
                  
                ]
            });
            });
            </script>
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

You have both the options, now the choice is yours.